# Is thread_local initialization performed on each thread, in the context of that thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

If I have a variable with `thread_local` storage class with a dynamic initializer, it presumably get initialized multiple times: once for at least every thread it is used on.

Does this initialization happen in the context of the newly created thread, or is possible that it happens on a different thread?

Specifically, will either of the following work:

```
thread_local int tid1 = pthread_self();

thread_local int tid2 = syscall(SYS_gettid);
```

... in the sense that `tid1` and `tid2` get the correct ID for the current thread.

Comment: The initialization happens only on the threads that runs it - it cannot happen on any other thread. Whether every thread initializes the variable is implementation defined I suppose. Heard, it takes a function call to access/modify such a variable - so use it sparringly.

Comment: @ALX23z Why couldn't it happen on any other thread?

Comment: `thread_local` variables are made to be accessed only by the current theard only. Once the thread ends they are no longer accessible and get destroyed. I haven't read the standart, and hypotheitically, one could instantiate most variables via an unrelated OS thread - but some classes have to be instantiated on the thread they run - or they won't work - which is why I highly doubt that any other thread makes the initializations.

Comment: @ALX23z - right, well the most likely candidate other than the current thread would be the thread that _creates_ the current thread, but good point about classes that want to be initialized on the current thread.  Current compilers seem to defer the initialization until first use, i.e., unlike dynamically initialized globals, they don't do the init unconditionally on thread creation, but rather check every time the variable is accesses if init has been run. That gives you "current thread" behavior but it's not clear if it mandated that way.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows and Visual C++, it is done through TLS (Thread Local Storage).
TLS functions run in the context of their threads.

More: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-local-storage)
and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/thread-local-storage-tls?view=vs-2019).

The comment by @ALX23z is correct - such variables have to be accessed by an OS function, or their memory address would be visible to everyone.

Of course, the compiler is also free to create different memory addresses with the same variable name. In that case TLS wouldn't be used and `&var` would be a different pointer for each thread. But that would require compiler-level work.